# Nissan Altima 2010 Transmission

Tags: transmission, cvt-transmission

Was a given a 2010 Nissan Altima by my mom's. The question is I feel like sometimes the transmission is a little jumpy and I know she has never changed the transmission fluid.(recommended every 30k). I have 85k on the car now. Should I go to the dealer and have them change it out?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, having the fluid changed is a good idea.

You may also want to consider if the vehicle needs a thorough service, if it has not had one recently.